# Navigation bar showing on sidemenu navigation ios xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I used sidebar navigation xamarin component in my app, but navigationbar is showing on the sidemenu, it does not slide with the navigation controller.

xamarin component: https://components.xamarin.com/view/sidebarnavigation

Here is my code.
public AgentDetails agent { get; set; }
        public SidebarController SidebarController { get; private set; }

```
    public RootController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

    }

    public override void LoadView()
    {
        base.LoadView();
        UIImageView img = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 120, 50));
        img.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Logo.png");
        img.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
        this.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(img);
        //this.NavigationItem.Title = true;

        //menuOpen.SetBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromBundle("Menu.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
        UIBarButtonItem back = new UIBarButtonItem();
        back.SetBackButtonBackgroundImage(UIImage.FromBundle("Back.png"), UIControlState.Normal, UIBarMetrics.Compact);
        this.NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = back;

        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 0, 0);

        var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
        MainTabController tab = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("TabPage") as MainTabController;
        SideMenuController side = storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SideMenu") as SideMenuController;
        side.rootController = this;
        tab.agent = agent;
        SidebarController = new SidebarController(this, tab, side);

        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
        menuOpen.TouchUpInside += MenuOpen_TouchUpInside;
        LoadSchedule();
    }

    void LoadSchedule()
    {
        AgentAPI agentData = new AgentAPI();
        agentData.EmpId = agent.PortalId;
        agentData.ScheduleHours((schedule) =>
        {
            JObject jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(schedule);
            if (jsondata["status"].ToString() == "200")
            {
                agent.Schedule = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Schedule>>(jsondata["activity"].ToString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void MenuOpen_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SidebarController.ToggleMenu();
    }
```

[image of my sidemenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zaO0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't embed the `RootViewController` in the `NavigationController`. 
Embed the ContentController instead.

For example , the code snippet in `RootViewController.cs` like this:

```
SidebarController = new SidebarController(this, new UINavigationController(new ContentController()), new SideMenuController());
```

Comment: Then what about the navigation button to open sidemenu, where would I place that since sidebarcontroller object initialized in the Rootcontroller

Comment: According to your code, you can create a subclass of `UITabBarController`, then add the UIBarButtonItem to the navigationbar in that subclass. Then assign the subclass to the TabBarController in your storyboard.

Comment: @ZeeshanShakil, did my answer help you?